# Visual Studio 2015 Hangs while creating cloud project

Tags: visual-studio, azure

While following the [Tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/)   I get stuck at step 12 and VS says its busy?
Kindly find the screen shot at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptZmm.jpg)
StackOverFlow says I can upload pics here only if I have 10 points.

Comment: I think you can really improve this question. All you did was post a tutorial link, which requires someone to read through it. And if the link dies, your question dies. You should include more info, maybe a screenshot...

Comment: Thanks David, I was unable to upload scren shot here however Imgur is good option.